# Dúvida entre realizar o clearfix utilizando um elemento no DOM ou um pseudo-elemento

Tags: css, float

Eu tenho que usar um `float: left` no meu logo e `float: right` no meu menu, porém o `background-color` desaparece e preciso corrigir com `clear: both`.

Minha dúvida é: qual a diferença entre usar um `<br>` após os itens flutuantes com `clear: both` e usar o pseudo-seletor `::after`, fazendo:

```css
::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Pois já vi gente usando assim pra limpar aquela baguncinha do *float.*

Answer (score 0):

A diferença é que, ao usar um `<br>` (ou qualquer outro elemento para fazer o *clearfix*), você está inserindo um elemento no DOM. Ao utilizar o pseudo-seletor `::after`, você insere um pseudo-elemento no DOM.

Veja alguns exemplos:

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #000;
}

.box {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="background: red;">1</div>
  <div class="box" style="background: green;">2</div>
  <div class="box" style="background: blue;">3</div>
  
  <br class="clearfix" />
</div>
```

Note, no exemplo acima, que utilizamos o `<br>` para fazer o *clearfix*. No entanto, não é necessário sequer mexer no HTML para arrumar isso. Pode-se utilizar um pseudo-elemento (criado com o `::after`):

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #000;
}

.box {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}

.container::after {
  content: ' '; /* Cria o pseudo-elemento */
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="background: red;">1</div>
  <div class="box" style="background: green;">2</div>
  <div class="box" style="background: blue;">3</div>
</div>
```

Como você viu, o efeito é o mesmo.

---

Para saber mais, sugiro a leitura do excelente artigo "[All about Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)". No entanto, é importante observar que, se os [navegadores do seu público-alvo suportarem](https://caniuse.com/flexbox), você pode utilizar o [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), que é uma alternativa mais moderna para os chamados *floated layouts*.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigada!

Comment: De nada, @SophiaYuno. :-) Veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.